# Prevent star (*) to be replaced with file list

Tags: bash, yui-compressor

I have a small Bash script which basically takes a JavaScript file, minifies it using yui-compressor, adds some string and stores it to a different file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH_OF_SOURCE='../some_directory/some_input_file.js'
PATH_TO_WRITE='some_output_file.js'
CONTENT_VAR=$(yui-compressor ${PATH_OF_SOURCE}) # minify JS file
CONTENT_VAR="{CONTENT_VAR} some_string_here" # Append a string
echo CONTENT_VAR > $PATH_TO_WRITE # Write to file
```

The problem is: The input JavaScript file contains some stars (*) inside strings like

```
var myString = 'Fields marked with * are required';
```

However, my Bash script replaces * with the file list of the current working directory, so I'll get `Fields marked with file1.js file2.js ... are required`

Of course, I don't want that. And unfortunately, any changing/overwriting of the original input file (like escaping) is out of question: Everything has to happen inside the script.

Comment: Disable wildcard expansion within the command-substitution, just do `CONTENT_VAR=$(set -f; yui-compressor ${PATH_OF_SOURCE})`, we are disabling it only in the sub-shell created by `$(..)`. should shouldn't be a problem for you.